# Chrome Extension native messaging not opening port

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to create a Chrome Extension that, among other things, needs to call a native windows app to get some data, particularly IP Address, and a Citrix User ID(it's obviously on Citrix).  Currently, I am unable to open the port in the extension, and I am just doing this all locally, on Windows 10, no Citrix.

My manifest file for the listener is:

```
{
    "name": "com.q.userid",
    "description": "My Application",
    "path": "C:\\Temp\\NativeMessageHost.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": [
      "chrome-extension://mbodcbioidcfdfhjgekeppinibhhnnmh/"
     ]
}
```

For the sake of simplicity/testing, my extension uses a browser action, that has a pop up with a text box, and I call my native app in the onKeyUp.  My JS for this is as follows:

```
  $(function() {
    $('#name').keyup(function(){
        var port;
            port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('userid');
            console.log(port);
            port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
                console.log('Received: ' + msg);
            });
            port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
                console.log("Disconnected");
            });
            port.postMessage({text: "hello"});

        });
    });
```

My Manifest File for the extension is:

```
   {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Hello World",
    "description": "Hello World",
    "version": "1.1",
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Hello World",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
    "permissions": [
        "nativeMessaging"
   ]
}
```

When I trigger the code, I get an output of 
Port {}
Disconnected

"Disconnected" is immediate.

From the windows task manager, I do not see the exe launching.

In the console of the extension I past in the line

```
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('userid');
```

Then I paste in

```
port.postMessage({text: "hello"});
```

That yields an uncaught error: attemting to use a disconnected port.

I added the registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER->SOFTWARE->Google->Chrome->NativeMessagingHosts->com.q.userid

default : c:\temp\manifest.json

I also tried it as
 default : c:\temp\manifest.json

the chrome log stated it was unable to find the manifest file for userid

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use `chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.q.userid');`

Comment: That did it, thank you!